# How to recreate a class with JavaPoet?

Tags: annotation-processing, javapoet

I'm trying to recreate a class using JavaPoet. 
What's the best way to do this?

Basically, I want to generate another class with one method with appended statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JavaPoet can’t easily modify existing code. This is potentially quite difficult because features like import resolution rely on parsing types properly.

You might be able to cheat by emitting a new file and then using a StringBuilder to manually concatenate imports and members. You might need some regexes.

Comment: would be great for us to learn from an example inlined if you can add so

Comment: Well then, I ended up relying on AspectJ to accomplish what I wanted to do.